# Creating ZIP archive and files for it the same time with Perl

Tags: perl, file, cgi

I have a code as following:

```
my $file = 'myFile.txt';
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
my $compressed = $zip->addFile($file, "newFilename");

if ($zip->writeToFileNamed('dir/test.zip') != AZ_OK)
{
    print "ERROR";
}
else
{
    print "DONE";
}
```

Pretty much easy!

The question is: is it possible to rewrite `$file = 'myFile.txt'` to put there a string, which contains some data (i.e.: "123455677889") and this data must be associated with some filename (say: "myFile.txt") which does NOT exist on the server. The other words:

1. we have (obtain or generate) some `$data = "12344566789abcselkjlkj";`
2. then we associate this data in some way with new file, which does not exist yet and must NOT exist ever on the server (even 1 second as a _temp).
3. The last step - we put this "virtual" file into the new archive and even then do not write on the disk, but sending as an output (**CGI**) to the user right from the webpage.

Every help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: I think [addString](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip#addString-stringOrStringRef-name-compressionLevel) is the closest to your need, but that still creates a file.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak Thank you. If I won't be able to find a better solution - I will use this and will remove files immediately after releasing them to the browser (I mean, after they have been downloaded). Thanks!

Comment: OK, I'm adding this as an answer, you may mark it as accepted if you take it as a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`addString`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip#addString-stringOrStringRef-name-compressionLevel) does exactly what you want.

```
# Create a file in the archive from a string.
my $string_member = $zip->addString('12344566789abcselkjlkj', 'myFile.txt');
$string_member->desiredCompressionMethod(COMPRESSION_DEFLATED);
```

Comment: `addString` doesn't create any files. There's nothing in the documentation suggesting it does, and I verified it using `strace`. Fixed your answer.